# Save result of countByKey ,countByValue in spark cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed

I am a newbie to spark programming and am using pyspark to develop my app

I have to calculate some statistics in spark and I need them in form of a pickled map. This is straightforward in local mode. But in cluster mode how do I accomplish this?

```
myDict= allData.map(lambda x :(x.mykey,x.myvalue).countByValue()
#pickle.dump(dict(myDict),pickleFile) This I can do in local mode
```

How do I store the results of myDict in cluster mode? Is this even possible?

Comment: `myDict` is a local data structure. What difference does it make if you run this locally vs on cluster?

Comment: how would the handle for the pickle file be passed to the program? this is the file where i want to store the map. and how would i access this file ?

Comment: For further processing in Spark? Why would you pickle for that?

Comment: No Not for further processing. This map has some statistics which will be need to be visualized in the next step